# .NET CF windows form can show Arabic Unicode text on title but not for labels?

Tags: .net, compact-framework, windows-ce, unicode-string

After installing Arabic.CAB (or Arabizer) on my Win CE 5.0 device , i can set a static Arabic string as my .NET CF's windows form's title by :

```
this.Text = "سلام";
```

and it works fine and i can see the Arabic text on my form's title bar correctly.but these lines of code do not work and all i see is squares! :

```
label1.Text = "سلام";
textBox1.Text = "سلام";
MessageBox.Show("سلام");
```

what's the difference between Form's title and content?
am i missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the font of the windows form is different with the font of its sub controls.

Comment: you are right. the Arabic.CAB copies "Times New Roman" font that is not by default in my windows folder. when i changed my sub-control's font from Arial/Tahoma to Times, it worked. thank you.